# Determine whether mixed mode auth is enabled without logging in?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, authentication, logins

Is it possible in SQL Server to determine whether mixed mode authentication is enabled without logging on to SQL Server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another approach is to *try* logging in, using SQL authentication, with an obviously fake account that won't succeed. You can then use notepad to open up the `ERRORLOG` file in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\$instance folder$\MSSQL\Log\` and see either this error...

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: **58**.
>   
> Login failed for user 'polly_wants_a_cracker'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only.
>   
>   
> *This means **mixed mode authentication is not enabled**.*

...or this one...

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: **5**.
>   
> Login failed for user 'polly_wants_a_cracker'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.
>   
>   
> *This means **mixed mode authentication is enabled**.*

I don't know that there is possibly a way to tell without either:

- logging in *successfully*
- having physical access to the box (or remote registry) in order to check either the registry configuration (as [Julien describes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160874/1186)) or the error log for the state/message when logging in *unsuccessfully*

Answer (score 18):

You can check it in the registry:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\ [instancename] \MSSqlServer
```

The current mode is recorded in the `LoginMode` key.

Values (DWORD) can be:

- 1 = Windows Authentication mode
- 2 = SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

Note:

- `0` is equivalent to `2`
- You still need access to the Registry (and the server)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this via PowerShell:

```
import-module sqlserver
$sqlserver = "ServerName"
$srv = Get-SqlServer -sqlserver $sqlserver
$srv.LoginMode
```

This will return output like this:

[image]